# How the memcmp on structure with integer variable in c lang compares. Result is not as expected

Tags: c, integer, comparison, memcmp

I have a structure with integer, I am comparing the struct by using memcmp, I don't want to use other memthods.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>

   typedef struct Foo 
   {
      int d;
   } Foo;

   int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
   {
      Foo one, two;
      int result;
   
      memset(&one,0,sizeof(Foo));
      memset(&two,0,sizeof(Foo));
    
      one.d = 1022;
      two.d = 1024;
    
      result = memcmp((void*)&one, (void*)&two, sizeof(Foo));
      printf("comp with assignment %d\n",result);
    
      if (result == 0) printf("Arrays are the same\n");
    
      return 0;
   }
```

memcmpa should return -1, but it returns 1. why ?
memcmp woth one.d = 1022 and two.d = 1023 will return correct value.
why is so?

Comment: It compares _bytes_, not `int`s - look at how an `int` looks at byte level and you'll see.

Comment: Look up `little endian` and `big endian`... Ted has pointed the way...

Comment: Another note: _"should return -1, but it returns 1"_ - It will return a negative, positive or `0`. Not `-1` , `1` or `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add two `printf`s in your code:

```
   typedef struct Foo 
   {
      int d;
   } Foo;

   int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
   {
      Foo one, two;
      int result;
   
      memset(&one,0,sizeof(Foo));
      memset(&two,0,sizeof(Foo));
    
      one.d = 1022;
      two.d = 1024;

      printf("%04x %04x\n", one.d, two.d);
    
      result = memcmp((void*)&one, (void*)&two, sizeof(one));
      printf("comp with assignment %d\n",result);
    
      if (result == 0) printf("Arrays are the same\n");
    
      return 0;
   }
```

Result:

```
03fe 0400
comp with assignment 1
```

You will see that the first byte of `one` is `0xfe` and the first byte of `two` is `0x00` (they are in opposite order as most modern machines are little endioan)  So `0xfe > 0x00` and `memcmp` returns `1`

Answer (score 0):

It compares *bytes*, not `int`s:

> `memcmp`- This function reads object representations, not the object values, and is typically meaningful for byte arrays only: `struct`s may have padding bytes whose values are indeterminate,

Look at how an `int` looks at byte level and you'll see it more clearly. It can be stored with the most significant byte first *or* last - and the result of `memcmp` will depend on that.

You can create your own `memcmp_debug` for this purpose.

Example:

```c
int memcmp_debug(const void *vpa, const void *vpb, size_t len) {
    const unsigned char *a = vpa, *b = vpb;

    puts("comparing these:");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        printf("%2d %02X %02X\n", i, a[i], b[i]);
    }

    puts("\ncomparing:");
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        int result = (int)a[i] - (int)b[i];
        printf("%2d %02X %02X  =>  %d\n", i, a[i], b[i], result);
        if(result) return result;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Possible output:

```
comparing these:
 0 FE 00
 1 03 04
 2 00 00
 3 00 00

comparing:
 0 FE 00  =>  254
```

.. and here it returned on the first byte compared (the least significant byte on my machine) and returned a positive value just like it did for you.